# VS Code C# auto-format in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

My team use a mixture of VS Code and Visual Studio for C# dev. We have VS Code setup to auto-format on save using the omnisharp extension and would like the same formatting option for our Visual Studio files. Is this possible?

At the moment if one dev pushes code from Visual Studio, and another opens it in VS Code, then saves, the formatting is changed resulting in a large diff. The only solution I can think of (aside from just using VS Code exclusively) would be to record which files have been changed in Visual Studio, then open and save them in VS Code.

Comment: There's an extension for it: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave (and then you 'just' have to get everyone to install it...)

Comment: Reformatting files on save is terrible option in multi-IDE environment. Turn it off.

Comment: @PeterB thank you! However its more the specific format that I'm after, not necessarily the format on save functionality. VS Code uses an omnisharp.json file, and it looks like id need to convert that to an .editorconfig file to work with the extension you linked?

Comment: @Sinatr i agree! Unfortunately thats not an option available to me :(

Comment: Perhaps the Code Style section in Visual Studio (.editorconfig)  can be helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided for now to just use the VS Code extension [Format Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jbockle.jbockle-format-files), running it with the glob option to reformat all my project files before committing them:

```
**/{ProjectName}.Tests/**/*.cs
**/{ProjectName{/**/*{SpecificFileName}*
```